# How can I get a variable php from server to android

Tags: php, android

Consider we have the following code in a `php` file:

```
$error = 'error';
echo "$error";
```

I search in internet and I find the example about this only and only using `JSON`. I want know how can I create a function to get the `$error` variable that has been sent from `php`. Please do not give me links and I want know How can I get the `$error`, I think the 
something like the following But really I do not know what should I do.

```
public void getVariable (String error)
{
How can I get the variable from php file?
}
```

in short: I want to have the contents of the `$error` variable in a java variable.

Comment: What class/method/ways are you using to make the call from android to server? The echoed string should be in the response from server to android.

Comment: The every request from server should come from an API, so you create an API in backend, API is just a function which returns the error.

Comment: @frz3993, my code is much like the link: [link](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89)  but it can not get variable from php. it has not this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpUrlConnection` to connect to the php script and `BufferedInputStream` to get the data

```
URL url= new URL("http://...yourfile.php");
HttpUrlConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoInput(true);

InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
String result = readStream(inputStream); // s now contains the value you need
```

Comment: if I have the content of the **$error** , it goes to the inputStream object and then it goes to the result object? as the result result object has the content of the **$error** ? In fact it is such a thing: **result = content of the $error** ??

Comment: Yes. the string variable `result` now contains the content of the `$error` variable.